# IE 8 Hover menu

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a sub nav which for some reason I can't fix for IE7,8

The drop down will always align to the left of the nav rather than the hovered element.

The CSS is LESS but if someone can shed some light

CSS - http://pastebin.com/tmMR9n3m
HTML - http://pastebin.com/r769n2Ka

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: Hi Brob. I think I know what your problem is. In you LESS stylesheet you are referencing all the elements within the <nav> element. Since this is an HTML5 element - older browsers dont know how to style them correctly. 
Check out:
http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/

A solution to this is to use the HTML5 shiv